# Find the shortest path between vertex, but have error in server

Tags: c++

I have task to find computer which could work as server, because it has the shortest path to other computers.

Inputs first row has number of computers.
Other row has numbers of computers which are connected.
Last row always have 0 0
Example:

```
5
5 4
1 2
4 3
1 4
0 0
```

Output first row contains minimal time (jumps) when all computers get message.
Second row has all the numbers of computers which can work as servers.
Example:

```
2
1 4
```

On my local computer everithing is working. But when I send my code in University server for testing, 2/5 public tests are working, but 3/5 gives me error:

```
Caught fatal signal 11
stderr  
*** Error in `solution': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000001a36940 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
[0x4bb811]
[0x4c47bb]
[0x4c7d87]
[0x42688e]
[0x429f47]
[0x42aa4d]
[0x400817]
[0x49a0b6]
[0x49a2aa]
[0x401039]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-005a3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 776099                             /box/solution
007a2000-007ab000 rw-p 001a2000 fd:01 776099                             /box/solution
007ab000-007b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01a1f000-01a42000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2b1ae7340000-2b1ae7349000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffd3bb6000-7fffd3bd7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffd3bfb000-7fffd3bfe000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fffd3bfe000-7fffd3c00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I cant find my mistake, hope someone could help.
My code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int BreathFirstSearch(int** matrix, int size, int row){//function to walk around matrix and find every path from vertex to vertex
    int pathLen=0;
    int q[size+1], dis[size+1], queue_input = 0, queue_output = 0, look_at;
    bool stop = false;
    for(int i=1;i<=size+1;i++){
        q[i]=0;//queue for element I need to look at
        dis[i]=-1; //to now if I have looked at it and to count how many jumps there are between row vertex and every other vertex
    }
    dis[row] = 0;//the row from matrix can go to itself with 0 jumps
    q[queue_input]=row;
    while(q[queue_output]!=0){
        look_at=q[queue_output];
        queue_output++;
        if(!stop){
            for(int col=1; col<=size; col++){//walking through every matrix collon
                if(matrix[look_at][col]==1 && dis[col]==-1){//if matrix collon has 1 to show that there is string between it and the row element. also check if it have already been ir queue
                    queue_input++;
                    q[queue_input]=col;//add collon to queue
                    dis[col]=dis[look_at]+1;//add +1 to path from row to collon element
                }
            }
        }
        int s=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=size; i++){
            for(int k=1; k<=size; k++){
                if(q[k]==i){
                    s++;//count how many elements row has
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(s==size) stop=true; //if row has as much elements as matrix size, then I know that there wont be more and can stop
    }
    int maxDis = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        if (dis[i] > maxDis){
            maxDis = dis[i];
        }
    }
    return maxDis;//return only farthest distance
}

int main(){
    ifstream fin ("serveris.in");
    ofstream fout ("serveris.out");
    if (fin.is_open()){
        int size, x, y;
        fin >> size; //read size of matrix from file
        int** matrix = new int*[size];
        for(int i = 1; i <= size; ++i){
            matrix[i] = new int[size];
        }
        int *result = new int[size];
        for(int i=1; i<=size; i++){//fill matrix with zeros
            for(int k=1; k<=size; k++){
                matrix[i][k]=0;
            }
        }

        while(fin.good()){
            fin >> x >> y;
            if(x!=0){//fill 1 in their places
                matrix[x][y]=1;
                matrix[y][x]=1;
            }
        }

        for(int row=1; row<=size; row++){//go through every row of matrix
            result[row]=BreathFirstSearch(matrix, size, row);//in result array I put in only farthest path
        }

        int min = result[1];
        for(int i=1; i<=size; i++){//find shortest path between vertex
            if(result[i]<min)min=result[i];
        }
        fout<<min<<endl;
        for(int i=1; i<=size; i++){//find in witch row/s this path was
            if(result[i]==min)fout<< i<<' ';
        }
    for(int i=1; i<=size; i++) delete[] matrix[i];
        delete[] matrix;
        delete[] result;
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Example is giving error on server. This one is working:

```
4
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Comment: You are accessing unallocated memory: matrix[size][size] or result[size]. int *result = new int[size]; means you allocate memory for 'size' elements from result[0] to result[size-1].

Comment: Oh thanks, you saved me :)